# Subfloor leveling

Tags: flooring, subfloor

I have a ~200sq ft room that I would like to install vinyl plank flooring in. The concrete subfloor is not flat. The concrete generally slopes from North to South and from East to West. I believe this sloping is ok since, based on my research, the subfloor needs to be flat, not level. Whats concerning is that there is a high spot ridge that runs down the center of the room along with a fairly sizable low spot. I plan on grinding down the ridge and filling in the low spot. Is this plan correct? Or should I be doing something different? Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: You could use a self-leveling compound, but for an area that size it could be a little expensive to pour that much.

Comment: most planks don't need it perfectly flat, so long as the slope is gentle (no ridges). Run planks long-wise left to right. You can fill the low spots with plywood underlayment or even paperboard, adding self-leveling mix around that to snug things up. I would also put the foam underlayment under it all; concrete is unforgiving and noisy, and the underlayment provides forgiveness for small floor un-evenness.